# Recurrence relation given by a polynomial

Tags: recurrence-relations

Consider non-homogeneous, first order, nonlinear recurrence
$$a(n+1)=P(a(n)),$$
where $P$ is a given polynomial.

Are there any general solutions to such a problem? How about generalization to exponential polynomials?

Answer (score 1):

With few exceptions, this does not have a closed-form general solution, even when $P$ is a quadratic polynomial.